# Why does scrapy spider return no output when scraping amazon?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, css-selectors

I was testing out the scrapy spider on the Amazon best-seller books pages (see URL below) but it returns weird price numbers or no output at all as you see in the output at the end (I only shared the output from 1 page). It might be something wrong with the css selectors but I am not sure. I would like the spider to save the output in the JSON file so I can quickly turn it into pandas dataframe for some analysis. This is the code I wrote in the terminal to run the spider: scrapy crawl amazon_booksUK -o somefilename.json

I know this is a lot to look through but if you have some time it would really help me out! :)

url = https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?i=stripbooks&bbn=266239&rh=n%3A266239%2Cp_72%3A184315031%2Cp_36%3A389028011&dc&page=1&fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1598942460&rnid=389022011&ref=sr_pg_1

**1. Spider code:**

```
import scrapy
from ..items import AmazonscrapeItem

class AmazonSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    page_number = 2
    name = 'amazon_booksUK'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?i=stripbooks&bbn=266239&rh=n%3A266239%2Cp_72%3A184315031%2Cp_36%3A389028011&dc&page=1&fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1598942460&rnid=389022011&ref=sr_pg_1'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        items = AmazonscrapeItem()

        # if multiple classes --> .css("::text").extract()
        product_name = response.css('.a-color-base.a-text-normal::text').extract()
        product_author = response.css('.a-color-secondary .a-size-base.a-link-normal').css('::text').extract()
        product_nbr_reviews = response.css('.a-size-small .a-link-normal .a-size-base').css('::text').extract()
        product_type = response.css('.a-spacing-top-small .a-link-normal.a-text-bold').css('::text').extract()
        product_price = response.css('.a-spacing-top-small .a-price-whole').css('::text').extract()
        product_more_choice = response.css('.a-spacing-top-mini .a-color-secondary .a-link-normal').css('::text').extract()
        # this only selects the element that has the image --> need stuff inside src (source attr)
        product_imagelink = response.css('.s-image::attr(src)').extract() # want attr of src

        items['product_name'] = product_name
        items['product_author'] = product_author
        items['product_nbr_reviews'] = product_nbr_reviews
        items['product_type'] = product_type
        items['product_price'] = product_price
        items['product_more_choice'] = product_more_choice
        items['product_imagelink'] = product_imagelink

        yield items

        next_page = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?i=stripbooks&bbn=266239&rh=n%3A266239%2Cp_72%3A184315031%2Cp_36%3A389028011&dc&page='+ str(AmazonSpiderSpider.page_number)+'&fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1598942460&rnid=389022011&ref=sr_pg_'+ str(AmazonSpiderSpider.page_number)
        if AmazonSpiderSpider.page_number <3:
            AmazonSpiderSpider.page_number += 1
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

**2. items.py:**

```
import scrapy

    class AmazonscrapeItem(scrapy.Item):
        # define the fields for your item here like:
        product_name = scrapy.Field()
        product_author = scrapy.Field()
        product_nbr_reviews = scrapy.Field()
        product_type = scrapy.Field()
        product_price = scrapy.Field()
        product_more_choice = scrapy.Field()
        product_imagelink = scrapy.Field()
```

**3. settings.py:**
I used the google bot user agent to avoid being banned when testing the scraper.

```
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'
```

**4. pipelines.py:**

```
class AmazonscrapePipeline:
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item
```

### OUTPUT

```
The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
(venv) (base) Eriks-MBP:scrapyTutorial erikhren$ cd amazonscrape
(venv) (base) Eriks-MBP:amazonscrape erikhren$ scrapy crawl amazon_booksUK -o mm.json
2020-09-01 15:01:43 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.3.0 started (bot: amazonscrape)
2020-09-01 15:01:43 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.2.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar  6 2020, 22:34:30) - [Clang 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.29)], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020), cryptography 3.1, Platform Darwin-19.6.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
2020-09-01 15:01:43 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2020-09-01 15:01:43 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'amazonscrape',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'amazonscrape.spiders',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['amazonscrape.spiders'],
 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; '
               '+http://www.google.com/bot.html)'}
2020-09-01 15:01:43 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: e57aa4639df179b5
2020-09-01 15:01:43 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2020-09-01 15:01:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-09-01 15:01:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-09-01 15:01:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['amazonscrape.pipelines.AmazonscrapePipeline']
2020-09-01 15:01:44 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-09-01 15:01:44 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-09-01 15:01:44 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-09-01 15:01:44 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.co.uk/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-09-01 15:01:44 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.amazon.co.uk/b?ie=UTF8&node=266239> from <GET https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?i=stripbooks&bbn=266239&rh=n%3A266239%2Cp_72%3A184315031%2Cp_36%3A389028011&dc&page=1&fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1598942460&rnid=389022011&ref=sr_pg_1>
2020-09-01 15:01:44 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.amazon.co.uk/books-used-books-textbooks/b?ie=UTF8&node=266239> from <GET https://www.amazon.co.uk/b?ie=UTF8&node=266239>
2020-09-01 15:01:45 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.co.uk/books-used-books-textbooks/b?ie=UTF8&node=266239> (referer: None)
2020-09-01 15:01:45 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.amazon.co.uk/books-used-books-textbooks/b?ie=UTF8&node=266239>
{'product_author': [],
 'product_imagelink': [],
 'product_more_choice': [],
 'product_name': [],
 'product_nbr_reviews': [],
 'product_price': ['11',
                   '.',
                   '12',
                   '.',
                   '9',
                   '.',
                   '6',
                   '.',
                   '9',
                   '.',
                   '9',
                   '.',
                   '6',
                   '.',
                   '8',
                   '.',
                   '30',
                   '.',
                   '13',
                   '.',
                   '11',
                   '.',
                   '10',
                   '.',
                   '7',
                   '.',
                   '6',
                   '.',
                   '24',
                   '.',
                   '39',
                   '.',
                   '20',
                   '.',
                   '34',
                   '.',
                   '6',
                   '.',
                   '48',
                   '.',
                   '52',
                   '.',
                   '47',
                   '.',
                   '14',
                   '.',
                   '20',
                   '.',
                   '17',
                   '.',
                   '14',
                   '.',
                   '71',
                   '.',
                   '34',
                   '.',
                   '34',
                   '.',
                   '44',
                   '.',
                   '44',
                   '.',
                   '89',
                   '.',
                   '40',
                   '.',
                   '31',
                   '.',
                   '39',
                   '.',
                   '12',
                   '.',
                   '24',
                   '.',
                   '66',
                   '.',
                   '68',
                   '.',
                   '17',
                   '.',
                   '289',
                   '.',
                   '14',
                   '.',
                   '20',
                   '.',
                   '44',
                   '.',
                   '26',
                   '.',
                   '13',
                   '.',
                   '100',
                   '.',
                   '60',
                   '.',
                   '20',
                   '.',
                   '107',
                   '.',
                   '222',
                   '.',
                   '21',
                   '.',
                   '39',
                   '.',
                   '20',
                   '.',
                   '60',
                   '.',
                   '61',
                   '.',
                   '60',
                   '.',
                   '22',
                   '.',
                   '40',
                   '.',
                   '18',
                   '.'],
 'product_type': []}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just have to use user-agent like this:

```
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36'
```

something like that a real browser uses

Comment: I did not see this edit coming. Thank you it works now!